# If Eren has the power of two of the nine titans, why can he only transform into the Attack Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I haven't watched S3/S4 yet, about to start them, but as far as I can tell Eren can only transform into an Attack Titan. When I google "founding titan," there's no images of it, which implies that it's more an ability than an actual titan. So why is it treated like one of the 9 if there is no actual titan associated with it?

Comment: These [guys](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-on-titan) may ultimately provide better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erin also lacks the major ability of the founding titan. The ability to control other Titans. This is because he does not have Royal blood.

It seems reasonable to conclude that he remains in the form of the Attack Titan for the same reason, the Founding Titan's form and powers are linked to the Royal bloodline.